# Why can't my iPhone 4 show edited music info?

Tags: itunes, iphone, music

When I use iTunes to edit various song attributes, like adding lyrics, album art, song titles etc, iTunes shows that the song is edited. However, when I look in my iPhone, it is still not edited. How can I make it show what I have edited previously?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use iTunes to remove the song from your iPhone, sync, then add the song back to you iPhone with another sync.  That will upload a fresh copy of the song with your new metadata to your iPhone.